# Get an input content through TERR Tools

Tags: r, spotfire, terr

I created in Spotfire a listbox element whith this id="8f4cb7a6368b422b8d6a4cdc31d7731d".

How could I retrieve the user selection in this listbox to insert it in an R script ?

I want to retrieve its selection because I need to use it in my R script.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here is a great example](http://spotfired.blogspot.com/2015/10/update-doc-property-trigger-ironpython.html) of how to set the input parameter in a R Script to a property control.

- Edit > Data Function Properties > Register New R Function
- Set up your input and output parameters
- Run function and set the input handler to document property